# Loop doesn't work properly

Tags: loops, scheme

So

```
(let loop ((p (- (length lst) 1)) (i 0) (l lst))
  (cond
    ((= p 0)  
     lst)
    ((= i p)  
     (loop (+ p -1) 0 l))
    ((> (vector-ref (convert lst) i) (vector-ref (convert lst) p)) 
     (loop (+ p 0) (+ i 1) (swap (convert l) i p)))
    ((< (vector-ref (convert lst) i) (vector-ref (convert lst) p)) 
     (loop (+ p 0) (+ i 1) l)))
```

it will return original state on `(= p 0)` when i send `lst` of `'#(3 2 1)` but when i run `swap` function separately it will return `'#(1 2 3)`. `p` is the last array and `i` is the first of the array.

Comment: So in the case where the elements are equal `=`, then the loop is finished? It will terminate at least. What does `convert` do? If argument is a vector why does the parameter name indicate that it is a list?

Comment: convert just changes to list to vector and condition = p 0 will terminate the process

Comment: Your conversions are what is ruining your result. `lst` is never altered yet that is what you are returning. the last should use `else` instead of `(> ...)` since if it isn't larger it is equal or smaller. No need to check it. I have no idea what this is supposed to do but its obvious why it shouldn't work. Your issues have nothing to do with named `let`.

Comment: Could you provide a minimal complete example, including the definitions of both `convert` and `swap`, as well as the value of `lst`? Make an example that we can run without having to guess. (see [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Comment: Thx Alex I realized i was constantly passing lst  instead of l after you mention lst . I think it works now. Swap just simply just swap two variable that is all it does and convert just converts list-> vector

Comment: If your problem is solved, you should post the answer and accept it so that this Questions is no longer marked as open.

Answer (score 1):

Use `l` instead of `lst` to have the *final* value returned, not the *original*.

You start from `l = lst`, and progress in the loop changing the `l` on each step.

When you hit the final condition, just return what you have built, `l`.

Answer (score 1):

`'#(3 2 1)` is vector notation.  A `(list '#(3 2 1))` as input should return `(#(1 2 3))`

However that's not the worst thing here. Coverting between list and vector multiple times in the same cond case signals that something is wrong. You are spending lots of time and memory to make a vector you only use one. My suggestion is to convert to vector on the way in, and to a list on the way out.

And a few notation improvements could be made. Typically a lisp function that converts between types is denotated with a "->" between the types. So `convert` should be (list->vector) and you should have a corresponding (vector->list). One function shouldn't do both at least not without explicit arguments to avoid getting the data type wrong.

Also `swap` should be `swap!` as it mutates the data structure in place.

Also there's a logic error. If two elements in the input list are equal, you'll fall through all your cond clauses and trigger an exception.

```
(let loop ((p (- (length lst) 1)) (i 0) (vec (list->vector l))
  (cond
    ((= p 0)  
     (vector->list lst))
    ((= i p)  
     (loop (- p 1) 0 l))
    ((> (vector-ref vec i) (vector-ref vec p)) 
     (loop p (+ i 1) (swap! vec i p)))
    (else 
     (loop p (+ i 1) l)))
```